# use of rowMeans, rowSums, colMeans, colSums

Tags: r

I am working with a matrix and the commands rowSums and rowMeans, colSums and colMeans. I have most of it working until I want to take the sum of rowSums, sum of colSums, mean of rowMeans, mean of colMeans. Please see last line of code below. rbind(matRow, colSums, colMeans).  Can you assist in correcting the lower 2x2 matrix in the matrix mat?  Commands such as rowSums[colSums] are producing errors.

## Input table of data

```
mydata=read.table("mydata.txt")
 mydata
  V1 V2 V3 V4
1  1  2  4  7
2  2  4  6  8
```

## convert table to matrix in R

```
mat=as.matrix(mydata)
mat
     V1 V2 V3 V4
[1,]  1  2  4  7
[2,]  2  4  6  8
```

## Add row and column names

```
rownames(mat) <- c("r1", "r2")
colnames(mat) <- c("c1","c2","c3","c4")
mat
   c1 c2 c3 c4
r1  1  2  4  7
r2  2  4  6  8
```

## Vital Statistics

```
dim(mat)
[1] 2 4
rowSums=rowSums(mat)
colSums=colSums(mat)
rowMeans=rowMeans(mat)
colMeans=colMeans(mat)
```

## Append rowSums to right of mat

```
matRow=cbind(mat,rowSums,rowMeans)
matRow
   c1 c2 c3 c4 rowSums rowMeans
r1  1  2  4  7      14      3.5
r2  2  4  6  8      20      5.0

#Append colSums and colMeans below matRow
#far lower R corner 2x2 is not correct
#see final computation
matCol=rbind(matRow,colSums,colMeans)
Warning message:
In rbind(matRow, colSums, colMeans) :
  number of columns of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 2)
matCol
          c1 c2 c3   c4 rowSums rowMeans
r1       1.0  2  4  7.0    14.0      3.5
r2       2.0  4  6  8.0    20.0      5.0
colSums  3.0  6 10 15.0     3.0      6.0
colMeans 1.5  3  5  7.5     1.5      3.0
```

Comment: name your summaries differently than the functions that produce them. call the column summary functions only after you `cbind`

Comment: I am getting the same result? Can you explain what you would cbind please. I am row binding at the end.

Answer (score 2):

Create the data:

```
mat <- matrix(c(1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 6, 7, 8), 
              nrow = 2,
              dimnames = list(c("r1", "r2"), 
                              c("c1","c2","c3","c4")))
```

Do the row summaries first

```
m2 <- cbind(mat, rowSums(mat), rowMeans(mat))
```

Now `m2` has different shape than `mat`, it has two more columns. Doing this you get the summaries instead of the `NA`s also for the summary columns, but not all of them make sense (like sum of row means..)

```
rbind(m2, colSums(m2), colMeans(m2))
```

In your example you calculated the summaries for the original matrix, so you had two rows and four columns, but the `matRow` had 6 columns, which did not match `colSums` (4 columns).

Answer (score 1):

R often recycles vectors; if it needs more elements it will go back to the start. In the example below the 1 get recycled to become length 5.

```
> rbind(1:5, 1)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    2    3    4    5
[2,]    1    1    1    1    1
```

Sometimes this is really useful, sometimes this is pretty dumb. I'm not sure what you think the bottom corner should contain, but here's how you could have missing values instead.

```
rbind(matRow, c(colSums, NA, NA), c(colMeans, NA, NA))

         c1 c2 c3   c4 rowSums rowMeans
r1       1.0  2  4  7.0    14.0      3.5
r2       2.0  4  6  8.0    20.0      5.0
colSums  3.0  6 10 15.0      NA       NA
colMeans 1.5  3  5  7.5      NA       NA
```

Comment: Thank you. I am modifying your code by putting in the answers rather than the 4 NA's. It gets me the correct table.  Cheers!  MM

Comment: No problem! If it has helped would you mind accepting my answer?